# 90s young adult novel: young girl in a boarding school where some students are actually werewolves

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, werewolf

I am looking for a series of young adult novels that I read in the early 90's. I read them in French but I believe they were originally written in English.

The story revolved around a young girl's boarding school where some of the residents were actually werewolves...

That is frankly all I can muster today, apart from the fact that these books got me completely hooked at the time.

There were at least 3 or 4 novels, but the series maybe went on through a dozen books...

Comment: Hi there! :) There's already good info in there, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, what did the cover look like? Were there other magical creatures as well, or only werewolves? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: "Girls' boarding school with werewolves" is pretty much a whole **subgenre** of speculative fiction. Random examples I found by Googling: [Alpha Girl](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alpha-Girl-7-Book-Series/dp/B01MUH97TS), [Werewolf Academy](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MQ7N2AK/), [Lonely Werewolf Girl](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lonely-Werewolf-Girl-Number-1/dp/0749942835). (*Alpha Girl* is the closest of these, but it was only published in 2013 onwards.)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for these too! I think these are the ones I was looking for and it may be your series too, the *[Private School](https://www.goodreads.com/series/67808-private-school)* series by Steven Charles. From [a review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/88772538?book_show_action=true) for the first book, *[Nightmare Session](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6346206-nightmare-session)*:

> The story starts fairly normal with a scholarship student at a summer session of an elite boarding school. However, when another student dies, the faculty is being kind of creepy and you're getting more questions than answers it is time to worry. Luckily for Jennifer she has some good friends at school and a local boy are interested in helping solve the mystery.
>
> Jennifer and Lee search the lab and are found. Lee is hurt, but Jennifer sees one of the faculty turn into a wolf in a chamber. They barely escape after burning the place down and Jennifer hopes it is all over now.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and add details that support this series being the answer? That will help anyone else who comes along later with a similar question.

Comment: Oh my God, I think you got it ! Thank you, I would never have found it on my own. I'm ordering the first book of the series right now. So excited !

Comment: @Eric: you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.